# How do you clone the attributes of a superclass's object in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, subclass

Let's say I have a subclass Sub to the class Super, and an instance of Super called super. How do I create a new instance of Sub that will automatically clone all of super's properties (and include the additional Sub properties)? Alternatively, can I create a new instance of Super and then change its class to Sub?

More detail:

class Value < String

```
attr_accessor ...fields...

def initialize(name, ...fields...)
    ...sets fields...
    super(name)
end

def ...methods...
end
```

end

class Extracted_Value

```
attr_accessor ...more fields...

def initialize(???)
    ???
end
```

end

I have a bunch of different instances of Value, and for each of them there are times when I might successfully make an extraction from an utterance, which means making a new Extracted_Value which contains information about how the extraction happened, but everything from Value needs to be cloned.

My other option is to try to make some sort of wrapper class instead of a subclass?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Also: what is your real life use case for this?

Comment: There are ways to do this, but it's really hard to know the correct way without knowing how/why you want to do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
class A
 attr_accessor :a1, :a2

 def initialize param1, param2  
   @a1 = param1
   @a2 = param2
 end  
end

class B < A 
  attr_accessor :b1
end
```

When you instantiate B class, you can call both of a1 and a2 from A (super) class and also you can call b1 . You can combine in initialize method of sub class wich parameters you want to set etc ...

```
b = B.new "foo", 3
puts b.a1 # "foo"
puts b.a2 # 3
```

Hope this is what you wanted ?

Comment: Continuing your example: say we already have
a = A.new "foo", 3
and we make changes to a over time, for example
a.foo = "blah"
I want to clone as much as I can when making b. Just calling A's initialize won't do that, it won't keep the "blah"

Answer (score 1):

You are wandering dangerously towards class variable land, and all the issues you get sharing variables across multiple object instances. That is almost always bad news.

If you have two objects which the same properties, but differing attribute values, those should be two instances of the same class that defines the properties, and not two separate classes.

Rather than trying to generate an instance of another class, you should clone the current instance to get a new instance of the class.

Therefore the answer should be:

```
sub = Sub.new 'foo', 3
sub_two = sub.clone
puts sub_two.a1 # 'foo'
```

The key thing is that by using clone, the new instance simply copies the attributes to the new instance, but doesn't share the attributes across the two objects. So you can then do this:

```
sub.a1 = 'bar'
puts sub_two.a1 # 'foo'
puts sub.a1     # 'bar'
```

Comment: Yes, that's the great explanation . I think it's calling the transmission parameters over value, isn't ?